what is the inverse of $f(x) = x + [x]$
we need to find the inverse of $f(x) = x + [x]$
$[x]$ is a floor function
the graph of this function looks like:

this function is one to one so $f^{-1}$ is a function
however, there are gaps in the domain of $f^{-1}$, would it be defined as a piecewise function with infinitely many pieces?
spivak's solution suggests the inverse for $f(x)$ does not exist because it is unbounded above and below on $[0, 5]$ (which is not the case, which makes me think if my interpretation of his $[x]$ is correct). so I am trying to figure out if I should pursue this any further

What does being invertible have to do with being bounded on $[0,5]$ or not? There's some major misunderstanding here.

Yeah, it seems unlikely Spivak would make such a huge error. Are you sure that part was talking about this function?

On the range of $f,$ we have $f^{-1}(y)=y-\frac{\lfloor y\rfloor}2.$ I'll leave you to specify the range of $f.$

i have no idea what boundedness has to do with it being invertible. because you have say ln(x), and you invert it as e^x no problem. but i have checked and re-checked that i am looking at the right question and the right answer. perhaps this is a discrepancy between editions of solutions book and the book itself, or something of that sort

I'll bet you anything that there a typo and the plus sign was meant to be minus.  If $f(x) = x -[x]$ we have function that is periodic and not at all injective and not invertibale.  It's not that $f$ inverse is "unbounded" but that for ever point in $x\in[0,.5]$ There would be infinitely many $f(y)=x$.

that sounds very plausible actually

But then "because it is unbounded above and below on [0,5]" is still a big ?HUH?
